# Len and substitute to return 0 if cell is blank?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm using `BYROW` to pull a string of dates from one sheet and make a list of those dates in a single cell on another sheet. Now I'm trying to use `LEN` and `SUBSTITUTE` to count the number of dates in that cell:

```
=LEN(M13)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M13,",",""))+1
```

I have to add the `+1` at the end of the formula to count the last date, but some cells have no dates, and I need those to pull a `0` if they stay blank. Does this make sense? So if I add a comma after the last date, it throws off my `BYROW` function that gets me the dates in the first place.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MRkacDUNoa0QXMYG5njBp7E7NepRARKXb4IEHjWnxsw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply nest the `LEN` inside an `IF` to first check the cell if it's empty, in which case it will output empty (or 0 if you want.)

Something like:

```
=IF(M2<>"",LEN(M2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",""))+1,"")
```

- IF M2 is not empty, output the result of the LEN
- IF M2 is empty, output empty (change the last `""` to `0` if you want a 0 instead)

Comment: That is beautiful. Thank you. Why is this all so hard to learn? I wish my brain was better-adapted to understanding all of this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You learn by utilizing it... Nesting an `IF` in this way comes in handy a lot of times, so if you understand **what** it is that we did here you can adapt it to whenever you need it